# Looping over an array as a value in a JSON (javascript/react)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JSON of team members:

```
[
  {
  "name": "Allie Armstrong",
  "title": "Head of Finance",
  "teams": ["Finance", "Europe"]
  },
....]
```

I map over it, it's fine.

```
{teamMembersList.map(teamMember => {
  return(
    <TeamMember 
      teamMembers={teamMember}
    />
  )
 })}
```

But the teams part comes together.
I would like to basically get teammember.teams[0], then teammember.teams[1] etc, so they can be in their own span. Instead of having them as FinanceEurope
The number of elements in this array varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I moved my JSON data into the js file as a const.
Then:

```
{teamMembersList.map(x => {
    return x.teams.map(teams => (
      <li key={x.id}>
        {teams}
      </li>
    ))
  })}
```

It works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

TRY :

```
{ if(teamMembersList.teams && teamMembersList.teams.length) {
    teamMembersList.teams.map(teamMember => {
      return( <TeamMember teamMembers={teamMember} />)
    })
   } else {
     return('')
   }
}
```

Also you need to check if `teamMembersList.teams` have some value because if it returns `undefined` / `null` OR string then it will not work and will give you error.

Comment: Sadly I get "teamMembersList.teams is undefined". Any idea?

Comment: ok does `teamMembersList`  also have multiple array ? if yes are you loop it in parent element ??

Comment: `[
  {
  "name": "Allie Armstrong",
  "title": "Head of Finance",
  "teams": ["Finance", "Europe"]
  },{
    "name": "Roger Muller",
    "title": "Chief Happiness Officer",
    "teams": ["HR","Europe"]
  },{ etc other similar team members..`

My array teamMembers list is an array of objects. The key teams in each object has a value of an array with a random number of strings in it. See above, it might not be correct what I'm saying.

Comment: @Vectosaur i have edited it please check. note i am not into react so if else statement might not work but try  `teamMembersList.teams && teamMembersList.teams.length` this logic before calling the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the solution and posted it :)